# Can I block questions coming from specific users?

Tags: support

Is there an option to not see questions put out by specific users on my front page? I don't want to block anybody from MSE, but I would like to be able to not see their questions on the main page. Presumably the answer is no.

Comment: (+1) I would like that feature too.

Comment: I was secretly hoping this would be one of the privileges you unlock ^^

Comment: There's [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3353/add-the-ability-to-ignore-users) on meta.SO and the accepted answer links to [this thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script), containing a script (I haven't tried it myself).

Comment: @t.b. do you know of some good online documentation on greasemonkey and how to install (?) scripts?

Comment: @OlivierBégassat You need to be using Firefox. Check out the [GreaseMonkey site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

You probably could implement something like this as a user script, but there is not SE-supported way to do that.